# SQL - combine matching by dense_rank() with a bussines rule

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, window-functions

Is there a way in SQL to join rows based on their order, but move the order based on some rows not matching other criteria?

**Problem:**

I have a table of client leads and a table of client transactions. I want to use a window function to match leads to transactions in a way that would join transactions with the oldest valid lead (or leads), **that haven't been matched yet**. In other words, after a lead is matched with a transaction, it should not be matched with any newer transactions (it should only be matched with transactions that client made that day). Easiest way to do that would be to use `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY date_column)` and join the two tables based on the rank in each partition.

However, each lead is only valid for 0-10 days. This means that some leads in a partition might not have a valid match in the transaction table (or vice versa) and should be excluded from the partition. This of course affects the rank of the following rows and causes results to be mismatched.

**Example and code**:

In this example transaction_id 1 matches with lead_id 1 and lead_id 2.
Transaction_id 2 matches with lead_id 3.
etc.

**leads**

| lead_id | lead_date | client_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-01-05 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-01-09 | 1 |
| 6 | 2022-01-30 | 1 |
| 7 | 2022-01-09 | 2 |
| 8 | 2022-01-10 | 2 |
| 9 | 2022-01-11 | 2 |

**transactions**

| transaction_id | transaction_date | client_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-04 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-01-17 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-01-15 | 2 |
| 6 | 2022-01-15 | 2 |
| 7 | 2022-01-17 | 2 |

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE #lead ( lead_id int, lead_date date, client_id int)

INSERT INTO #lead
SELECT *
FROM 
( VALUES
     (1, '20220101', 1 )
    ,(2, '20220101', 1 )
    ,(3, '20220102', 1 )
    ,(4, '20220105', 1 )
    ,(5, '20220109', 1 )
    ,(6, '20220130', 1 )
    ,(7, '20220109', 2 )
    ,(8, '20220110', 2 )
    ,(9, '20220111', 2 )
) x (lead_date, lead_id, client_id)

CREATE TABLE #transaction (transaction_id int, transaction_date date, client_id int)
INSERT INTO #transaction
SELECT *
FROM (
VALUES
     (1, '20220102',1)
    ,(2, '20220103',1)
    ,(3, '20220104',1)
    ,(4, '20220117',1)
    ,(5, '20220115',2)
    ,(6, '20220115',2)
    ,(7, '20220117',2)
) x (transaction_id, transaction_date, client_id)
```

**Expected result:**

| lead_id | lead_date | client_id | transaction_id | transaction_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20220101 | 1 | 1 | 20220102 |
| 2 | 20220101 | 1 | 1 | 20220102 |
| 3 | 20220102 | 1 | 2 | 20220103 |
| 5 | 20220109 | 1 | 4 | 20220117 |
| 7 | 20220109 | 2 | 5 | 20220115 |
| 7 | 20220109 | 2 | 6 | 20220115 |
| 8 | 20220110 | 2 | 7 | 20220117 |

Following statement join client leads to transactions based on 10 day validity:

```
SELECT *
FROM #lead l
JOIN #transaction t
    ON l.client_id = t.client_id
    AND DATEADD(DD,10, l.lead_date) > t.transaction_date
```

Note that using `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY date_column)` to calculate the order of the rows in both tables and then simply joining them according to their rank does not work. In my example transaction_id 3 should not be part of the result, since lead_id 1, 2 and 3 have already been matched to earlier transactions. Therefore there are no valid leads to match with transaction_id 3.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
    l.lead_id
    ,l.lead_date
    ,l.client_id
    ,t.transaction_id
    ,t.transaction_date
    ,lead_rank = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY l.client_id ORDER BY l.lead_date)
    ,transaction_rank = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.client_id ORDER BY t.transaction_date)

FROM #lead l
JOIN #transaction t
    ON l.client_id = t.client_id
    AND DATEADD(DD,10, l.lead_date) > t.transaction_date
) x
WHERE lead_rank = transaction_rank
```

EDIT:
If we change date value of lead_id 4 to 20220108 it is easier to visualize the problem:

[image]

Colors are used to indicate a desired match. In the join clause transaction_id 3 is joined to lead_id 1-3. This is because it is less than 10 days older than a lead. After we rank all the leads and transactions, transaction_id 3 is matched with lead_id 4 (because of the same dense_rank value). This is, however, not a valid match because a transaction can't be older than a lead. Therefore, the order of the rest of the transactions is incorrect and transaction_id 4 is matched to lead_id 5 instead of lead_id 4 etc.

How do I solve this issue? Is there a way how to utilize window functions here without using loops or multiple statements? I feel like I'm missing a simple solution to this, but i can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: formatting (the tables in your question) should not be that hard 

Comment: @Luuk Thanks, I have no idea what I did wrong. The tables looked ok in preview mode, then after posting, the formatting was lost.

Comment: You probably hit this [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404376/rendered-view-requires-blank-line-before-and-after-tables-but-preview-accepts)

Comment: Maybe adding this condition `and lead_date < transaction_date` to the where clause will fix the issue, [check this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IsA1wohb)

Comment: @Ahmed It only works by accident. If we change date of lead_id 4 to 20220108, it should match to transaction_id 4, but this lead 4 is skipped, because dense_rank will match it with transaction_id 3 and then drop it on `lead_date < transaction_date ` condition. [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/zzyM_htZ)